# ibm cloud object storage Error: connect (ETIMEDOUT 10.1.129.66:443)

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage, cloud-object-storage

I was implementing the [following node.js code](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-gs-dev)

I have created COS but there is an error in response

```
import S3 from "ibm-cos-sdk/clients/s3.js";


var config = {
    endpoint: 's3.private.jp-tok.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud',
    apiKeyId: 'xxxx',
    serviceInstanceId: 'crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/dbad72afdcb81fac6df4:3bf9d86f-811f-480b-af51-ab1401c5e643::',
    signatureVersion: 'iam',
    region:"jp-tok"
    
};

var cos = new S3(config);

var request = cos.listBuckets();
request.on('complete', function(response) { console.log(response) }); // register a callback
request.send();

export default cos
```

The response I got after a while was:

```
  request: Request {
    domain: null,
    service: Service {
      config: [Config],
      endpoint: [Endpoint],
      _events: [Object],
      MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
      CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
      _clientId: 1
    },
    operation: 'listBuckets',
    params: {},
    httpRequest: HttpRequest {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/',
      headers: [Object],
      body: '',
      endpoint: [Object],
      region: 'jp-tok',
      _userAgent: 'ibm-cos-sdk-nodejs/1.13.1 win32/v18.16.0',
      stream: [ClientRequest]
    },
    startTime: 2023-07-27T09:12:24.128Z,
    response: [Circular *1],
    _asm: AcceptorStateMachine { currentState: 'complete', states: [Object] },
    _haltHandlersOnError: false,
    _events: {
      validate: [Array],
      afterBuild: [Array],
      restart: [Array],
      sign: [Array],
      validateResponse: [Array],
      send: [Array],
      httpHeaders: [Array],
      httpData: [Array],
      httpDone: [Array],
      retry: [Array],
      afterRetry: [Array],
      build: [Array],
      extractData: [Array],
      extractError: [Array],
      httpError: [Array],
      beforePresign: [Array],
      complete: [Array]
    },
    emit: [Function: emit],
    signedAt: 2023-07-27T09:13:29.511Z
  },
  data: null,
  error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.1.129.66:443
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -4039,
    code: 'TimeoutError',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '10.1.129.66',
    port: 443,
    time: 2023-07-27T09:13:50.548Z,
    region: 'jp-tok',
    hostname: 's3.private.jp-tok.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud',
    retryable: true
  },
  retryCount: 3,
  redirectCount: 0,
  httpResponse: HttpResponse {
    statusCode: undefined,
    headers: {},
    body: undefined,
    streaming: false,
    stream: null,
    _abortCallback: [Function: callNextListener]
  },
  maxRetries: 3,
  maxRedirects: 10
}
```

**what i am doing wrong(i am using a lite account which i got for IBM hackchallenge india 2023 )

the main aim is to make a API that stores the pdf file sent in base64 form
with a key and get the pdf when needed

i have a feel that this error is due to my account type as IBM cloud function also didn't work**

Comment: Is this a real API key?

Comment: yes @data_henrik

Comment: Great - do you want your account hacked?

Comment: Ok, so it will only get hacked for few days. And the error you are receiving is due to the private endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question, will keep this in mind @data_henrik

Comment: @Jagnathreddy this is not related to your account type. As suggested, try other endpoints